# Retain factor labels in linear model results

Tags: r, lm

How does one retain labels in linear models? How to have the slope labelled `Bar` or `xBar` in the coefficient table below?

```
dat <-  data.frame(
  y = c(1:3, 10:12),
  x = gl(2, 3, labels = c('Foo', 'Bar'))
)

coef(summary(mod <- lm(y ~ x, dat)))
#             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)      6.5  0.4082483  15.92168 0.0000909619
# x1              -4.5  0.4082483 -11.02270 0.0003850677
```

Actual use case is more complicated, tens of linear models with tens of variables. I do realize that I could write my own function that both retrieves the labels and fits the model, but I wonder if I am missing something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already works like that for me:

```
dat <-  data.frame(
  y = c(1:3, 10:12),
  x = gl(2, 3, labels = c('Foo', 'Bar'))
)

coef(summary(mod <- lm(y ~ x, dat)))
#             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)        2  0.5773503  3.464102 0.0257214207
# xBar               9  0.8164966 11.022704 0.0003850677
```

Comment: I see. You are right. I forgot to try in a clean R session. Must've been me playing around with contrasts (more likely) or some package I loaded that caused the issue.